# How to merge results of OPENJSON into single list and remove duplicates?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like:

[image]

I would like to use `OPENJSON` to make these ids into a single list:

```
1001
1002
1003
5
6
```

And also to remove any duplicates if possible. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OPENJSON` in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Users] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('[1001,1002,1003]')
,('[5]')
,('[6]')
 
Select Distinct B.Value
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select * from OpenJSON([Users]) ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Value
1001
1002
1003
5
6
```